# Floating view over the whole application

Tags: android, view

I need to have a floating view over all of my application.
I can use Window_service but I don't need my view to be outside of the app.
Only inside my app.

I also don't want the user to see "draw on other app" permission.
How else can I do it?

Comment: You can build your application inside an Activity that have your floating view and fragments, so when you need to change the "background" content you will just alter the fragment...

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something similar to this. In my case, I wanted all of my logging statements to be shown above the whole application (Similar to the `Developer Options -> Show CPU Usage` settings in an Android device).

In my case, I just wanted to display a `TextView` on top of the app, but you can pretty much replace it with your own layout.

Here's an example of the code I used:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.BackgroundColorSpan;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OverlayService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private TextView mTextView;
    private Spannable mSpannable;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public OverlayService getService() {
            return OverlayService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mTextView = new TextView(this);
        mTextView.setTextSize(10);
        mTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, 0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(mTextView, params);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {

        mSpannable = new SpannableString(text);
        mSpannable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xD993d2b9),0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);           

        // simple logic to only display 10 lines
        if(mTextView.getLineCount() > 10) {
            mTextView.setText(mSpannable);
        } else {
            mTextView.append(mSpannable);
        }
        mTextView.append("\n");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mTextView != null) {
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.removeView(mTextView);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just connect with this Service from your Activity and set it's text, like so:

```
ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

                        @Override
                        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                                LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
                                mService = binder.getService();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                        }
                };

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, OverlayService.class);
                context.bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                mService.setText("Sending a test message");
```

You would of course need to destroy that service as soon as the user leaves the app if you don't want it to be on top of other apps.

Comment: Doesn't this require a permission though?

Comment: Ah ha, good point, yes it does. Can't remember which one, but I think it was SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW.

Comment: I need one without "draw on other apps" permission.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that after I replied ha. What about creating a custom Toast message? You can add your own custom layout to the Toast and and also, you can pretty much keep a Toast open for whatever amount of time you want. Here's a simple hack I developed a couple of years ago: https://github.com/quiqueqs/Toast-Expander

Comment: But that would be a default Toast...  I need a complex View. with linear layout and two buttons..

Comment: You can actually customize the layout of the Toast. I have an app which does that, checkout the screenshots here, those little yellow post it notes are actually Toast messages: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thirtymatches.calleridnotes.lite

Comment: Here's a link on how to customize Toast layout: http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/customiozing-toast-in-android.html

Comment: Thanks, I know I can customise it. but I sure can't add animation.. The animation part is very important. I also need it to be clickable, could it be clickable with a custom Toast?

Comment: You got me there. I don't think Toasts support click events. Maybe you can have a look a the actual Toast source code and see if you can at least figure out the view on top of other views part: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Toast.java Good luck!

Comment: @roiberg how did you meet your requirement? I have same requirement and looking for solution since last three days. Your guidance would make my day..